# ¿Cómo hacer Web Scraping "interactivo" con BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web, scraping, plugin

Muy buenas, estoy scrapeando las imágenes de la siguiente web:

https://www.fungipedia.org/hongos

A la hora de entrar a cada link individual de cada seta, las imágenes se encuentran dentro de un wrapper de imágenes, en este caso del plugin "Simple Image Gallery Pro" (v3.0.6):

https://www.fungipedia.org/hongos/abortiporus-biennis.html

¿Cómo puedo acceder a estas imágenes desde BS4 y scrapearlas? El 'src' no me deriva al plugin directamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Muchas gracias y un saludo!

Comment: Sería útil que, en vez de tener código en capturas de pantalla, lo tuvieras en `texto formateado de Markdown`. Así todos podemos ver mejor, y ayudarte mejor ;)

Comment: Para tu caso específico, no es el jpg que está en el style, dentro del background-image?

Answer (score 1):

La ruta de las imágenes que pinta el plugin la tienes en los atributos `href` de las etiquetas `<A>`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

domain = 'https://www.fungipedia.org'
url = domain + '/hongos/abortiporus-biennis.html'

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

for item in soup.select('.sigProLinkWrapper a[href]:not([href=""])'):
    print(domain + item.attrs.get('href'))
```

Comment: ¡Me ha sido muy útil! Millones de gracias!